# One day one event only for calendar bootstrap year

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, calendar

```
clickDay: function(e){

      addEvent({ date :e.date});    

     }
```

im having this function where the user click the day will open a modal.

but i want to limit the day only one event, meaning the modal cannot open when user click the day that already has an event.

[calendar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwkiS.png)

```
 <script>
   var dataSource = [];
<c:forEach items="${newCalendar}" var="newCalendar">            


            var startDate = new Date(${newCalendar.calendarYear},${newCalendar.calendarMonth
                                     -1},${newCalendar.calendarDay});

            var endDate = new Date(${newCalendar.calendarYear},${newCalendar.calendarMonth
                                     -1},${newCalendar.calendarDay});                      

        var newData = {                         
                            id: ${newCalendar.calendarId},
            name: '${newCalendar.calendarType}',
                            location : '${newCalendar.calendarDesc}',
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate: endDate,
                            color: '${newCalendar.calendarColor}'

        };
            dataSource.push(newData);

</c:forEach>      
   </script>
```

this is where the array of data source

```
    function addEvent(event) {     

$('#add-modal input[name="event_start_date"]').datepicker('update', event ? event.date : '');       
$('#add-modal').modal();

  }
```

this is the modal

OR

I'm also making a edit modal where the user can edit the event of the day, so im thinking like the clickDay function can be if else statement where if there is data in the date, it will show the edit modal,otherwise it will show the add modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clickDay: function(e){      
      if(e.events.length === 0){
           addEvent({ date :e.date}); 
      }              
     }
```

checking the day whether there is an event or not